# Is accessing from QML to C++ objects which are running in main thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qml, qtquick2

I've noticed that main thread id is equal to qml thread id. So. Is it correct that I can access `controller` object's `Q_PROPERTY` and use it otherwise simultaneously from main thread (where it was created) and QML thread (which are the same as I see)? And is it correct that if I will move `controller` object to other thread, set it as a context property there would be race condition? Can I even do some synchronization or this is totally incorrect and I should create context properties from objects which belong to the main thread only (or even only call `qmlRegisterType` and create objects which are written in C++ only in QML itself) to prevent races?

Comment: What is `controller`?

Comment: It's as safe as risky, for your `controller` (about which I know nothing) could easily freeze the UI.

Comment: Could you provide a sample code expalining what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Downvoted. You should provide a more defined operational context.  Like this is just chit-chatting. You cannot `moveToThread` with QML but you can create `QRunnable` and `QThread` and register them as context properties. Then you can use `Connections` to bind to them and receive results. Using signal would be always easier. For what concerns accessors of `QPROPERTY` it really depends on the context but thread-safety could be required. Edit the question and provide a clear context and setting so that people can advice with the *best* solution for your problem.